# Exponential inequality, with x being in exponent as well being the base

Tags: inequality

I have tried separating using exponential rules couldn't solve that way. Next I tried using log to bring down the exponent, still couldn't do it.

> $$5x^{7x+3}>5^{-3}$$

Comment: It seems to be false. $x^{7x+3}$ is zero at the limit $x\rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem like being analytically solvable. Nevertheless, if you manage to show for example that the left-hand-side function is strictly increasing, you could be done be guessing the equality case.

Answer (score 1):

You can change to base "e" rather than x using $a^b= e^{b ln(a)}$ so you can write $5x^{7x+ 3}= 5e^{(7x+ 3)ln(x)}$.  Since a region satisfying an inequality always has the region where the **equality** is satisfied,  would first look at $5x^{7x+3}= 5e^{(7x+ 3)ln(x)}= 5^{-3}$.  Of course, then, $e^{(7x+3)ln(x)}= 5^{-4}= \frac{1}{625}$.  Taking the natural logarithm of both sides of that $(7x+ 3)ln(x)= ln\left(\frac{1}{625}\right)= -6.43775$.  As Tig La Pomme said, that can not be solve "analytically" (in terms of the usual functions though you might be able to get it into a form you could solve using the "Lambert W function" which is defined as "the inverse function to $f(x)= xe^x$.